# If the rank of an $m\times n$ matrix is $n$, does that imply that the columns are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question to solve:

> Let $A=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
> 1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
> 2 & -3 & 2 & 0 \\
> -1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
> -3 & 2 & 0 & 3\end{array}\right]$ and $\vec{b}=\left[\begin{array}{r}2\\3\\6\\9\end{array}\right]$.
>
> (a) Are the columns of $A$ lineraly independent?

The first idea that comes to mind is to find the rank of $A$... It is my assumption that if $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ has only the trivial solution then the columns must be linearly independent... but I can't find anything in my text that supports this theory.

Comment: But $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ having only the trivial solution is the definition of linear independence of the columns, so your theory is correct.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your title question: Yes. Indeed, if the rank of the matrix is equal to the dimension of the column space of the matrix, then indeed, the columns are linearly independent.

What happens when the rank of the matrix is less than the column space?

Comment: If the rank of $A$ is less than $n$ then it follows that there is a free variable in the linear system, and there has to be an infinite number of solutions to $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$.

Comment: Indeed, and the columns are linearly dependent, by the rank-nullity.

Answer (score 0):

> If the rank of an $m \times n$ matrix is $n$, does that imply that the columns are linearly independent?

Yes.  In fact, sometimes the rank of a matrix is defined as the size of the largest collection of linearly independent columns of $A$.

---

The set $$\{\vec{x}:A\vec{x}=\vec{0}\}$$ is the [null space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29) of $A$.  By the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), $$\mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{null}(A)=n.$$  So, if we show the nullity of $A$ is $0$ (i.e., $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ has the unique solution $\vec{x}=\vec{0}$), then we can conclude rank of $A$ is $n$, and its columns therefore must be linearly independent.